# BufferInputStream vs ByteArrayInputStream

Tags: java, file-io, inputstream

Here are three ways to read an entire file into memory before processing it:

Approach A:

```
fis = new FileInputStream(file);
bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
dis = new DataInputStream(bis);
```

Approach B:

```
ByteArrayInputStream bi =
    new ByteArrayInputStream(
        org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file))
```

Approach C:

```
File file = new File(yourFileName);
RandomAccessFile ra = new RandomAccessFile(yourFileName, "rw"):
byte[] b = new byte[(int)file.length()];
try {
    ra.read(b);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Why would I prefer one approach over another?
Are there any specific use-cases that call for one approach over another?
Why not use a fixed-length `byte[]` instead?

Comment: Your 3 cases do 3 different things. Case A doesn't read anything. Case B reads into a byte array, then opens a stream on the byte array. Case C reads into a byte array. What do you really want to achieve?

Comment: I think he's asking which should he use to read a file: a) regular java streams b) Bytearray stream or c) RandomAccessFile

Comment: A fourth method, and probably the most efficient, is [Files.readAllBytes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllBytes%28java.nio.file.Path%29)(Paths.get(yourFileName)) .

Comment: Is it only about efficiency  - or are there more specific situations that led to so many possible alternatives? e.g Why would a ByteArrayInputStream come into existence ,when we have a buffer-backed solution in BufferedInputStream anyways?

Comment: The title of the question is misleading.

Comment: Why would you want to read all the bytes of a file into memory at once?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you need anything special in terms of capabilities (e.g. random access), an InputStream wrapped into a BufferedInputStream is the general purpose choice for reading sequentially from any kind of data source that provides a streaming capability.

This will provide reasonable performance (through buffering), the code is generic in that it can process any stream, and also very important - the size of processable streams isn't limited by the available heap memory by this idiom.

So unless you have a very compelling reason to code against a special case API, use a standard InputStream and wrap it as needed.

---

**EDIT:** In response to the questions asked in the comment by @IUnknown:

> 1. What is the approach in the case of a random access - I thought BufferedInputStream is the preferred solution even in that case?

There is no generic interface for random access. You thought wrong. You could at least be so courteous to study the basics of basics: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/

> 2. the size of processable streams isn't limited by the available heap memory - the buffer must be having a limit.Are you saying that the internal array automatically re-sizes if its filled up while reading?

Again, thats covered in the basics (see above). With ByteArrayInputStream you need a byte[] to hold the entire stream. How's that *not* limited by memory? (even worse, its also hard capped by max array size).

> 3. Is there any difference in the buffer behavior between a Buffered stream and a ByteArray stream - I thought they are backed up by similar buffer behaviour

I don't know what to say. You thought wrong. Set aside the basic facts they both extend InputStream and somehow use a byte array internally (and technically either could be implemented without using any array, its just the most natural way to do it). They have *nothing* in common. A BufferedStream hold a small dynamic portion of *another* stream. ByteArrayInputStream was covered in 2.

**Advice:** People here will gladly advise you on which tool to use for which job. But don't expect to be spoon-fed. Show *some* effort, stackoverflow isn't a tutoring site. Stop "thinking" and start "learning" - the tutorials are out there and have been since the dawn of the language.

Comment: 1.What is the approach in the case of a random access - I thought BufferedInputStream is the preferred solution even in that case?
2. the size of processable streams isn't limited by the available heap memory  - the buffer must be having a limit.Are you saying that the internal array automatically re-sizes if its filled up while reading?
3.Is there any difference in the buffer behavior between a Buffered stream and a ByteArray stream  - I thought they are backed up by similar buffer behaviour

Comment: @IUnknown 1. Buffering with random access is pointless, as what you just buffered from the last time you read is probably not what you're going to read next. 2. The internal byte array of `BufferedInputStream` is fixed in length. 3. The difference is that the `BufferedInputStream` doesn't read everything into memory at once, which is good.